# Django and Javascript. Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

**Solución**: "Eso creo que pasa cuando intentas parsear a json algo que no se puede, como una respuesta vacía o texto plano. Prueba a hacer en vez de res.json(), res.text(). Y si la respuesta es vacía, no puedes hacer un res.json()".

Tengo un formulario el cual al momento de enviarlo, recibo la información por javascript para realizar una serie de validaciones y enseguida por fetch envió la información al servidor (una api sencilla creada con django). El código cuando lo trabajaba en un etorno de desarrollo funcionaba correctamente pero ahora que lo trabajo en un entorno de producción y lo desplegué en heroku me da el error. El código es el siguiente:

```
formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('https://portafolioadrian.herokuapp.com/contacto', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        nombre: document.querySelector('#nombre').value,
        correo: document.querySelector('#correo').value,
        telefono: document.querySelector('#telefono').value,
        mensaje: document.querySelector('#form__message').value,
        terminos : document.getElementById('terminos').checked,
      }),
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'), "Accept": "application/json", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.success) {
        formulario.reset();
    
            document.getElementById('form__message-success').classList.add('form__message-success-active');
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementById('form__message-success').classList.remove('form__message-success-active');
            }, 5000);
    
            document.querySelectorAll('.form__group-correct').forEach((icono) => {
                icono.classList.remove('form__group-correct');
            });
      }else{
        document.getElementById('form__message').classList.add('form__message-active');
      }
    })  
});
```

Al momento de enviarlo, por consola me da el siguiente error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
> position 0

El urls.py de la app es esta:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contacto, name='contacto'),
    path('mensajes/', views.mensajes, name='mensajes'),
]
```

Y la view es la siguiente:

```
def contacto(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        nombre = data['nombre']
        correo = data['correo']
        telefono = data['telefono']
        mensaje = data['mensaje']
        terminos = data['terminos']

        instancia = Contacto.objects.create(nombre = nombre, email = correo, telefono = telefono, mensaje = mensaje, terminos = terminos)
        instancia.save()

        return JsonResponse('success')

    else:
        return render(request, 'contacto/contacto.html')
```

Muchas gracias a cualquier aporte.

Comment: Tienes una muestra de los datos que regresan del servicio?

Comment: Eso creo que pasa cuando intentas parsear a json algo que no se puede, como una respuesta vacía o texto plano. Prueba a hacer en vez de `res.json()`, `res.text()`. Y si la respuesta es vacía, no puedes hacer un res.json()

Comment: @Arriel Disculpe, con muestra de datos a que se refiere? deberìa retornar un success pero a la segunda promesa (.then) no pasa, desde las herramientas del navegador tambièn averiguè que el status es 301 moved permanently

Comment: Entonces, Fernando, disculpe, pero fallo en entender cuál es su problema? A mi me parece que está intentando *parsear* una respuesta que **usted** supone es `json`, pero en realidad es un `301`, y la url donde se ha movido viene en los headers `Location`, como lo indica [este documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location). Si estoy equivocado, por favor indique, **explícitamente** cuál es su problema/pregunta.

Comment: @Suso Esa era la causa de mi problema, ya quedò solucionado. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Arriel Igualmente sus aportes, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @FernandoCedeño podrias, por fa colocar la respuesta a la pregunta, de esta forma queda registro por si a alguien se le presenta el mismo problema